# Apache: setup a separate SSL certificate for each virtual host

Tags: apache-httpd

I have generated lets encrypt(stage mode) certificate and install it in my web server, my problem when checking the fingerprint of each one I see it different from what the browser shows, even worse, the browser shows only one certificate for all domains.
For both domains I see this: [image]
The key size is correct, but the fingerprint is different, why is that?

My `httpd.conf`

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

Listen 443 https
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

ServerName 15.188.158.148:80
#ServerName highschoolhelper.org

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %v %V %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>


EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
IncludeOptional conf.d/domains/*.conf
```

Each vhost config has a config similar to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName apple.highschoolhelper.org
    ServerAlias apple.highschoolhelper.org www.apple.highschoolhelper.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apple.highschoolhelper.org/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@apple.highschoolhelper.org
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    LogLevel warn
    <Directory /var/www/html/apple.highschoolhelper.org/public_html>
        IndexIgnoreReset ON
        IndexIgnore .well-known

        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/apple.highschoolhelper.org-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/apple.highschoolhelper.org-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName apple.highschoolhelper.org
    ServerAlias apple.highschoolhelper.org www.apple.highschoolhelper.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apple.highschoolhelper.org/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@apple.highschoolhelper.org
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    LogLevel warn
    <Directory /var/www/html/apple.highschoolhelper.org/public_html>
        IndexIgnoreReset ON
        IndexIgnore .well-known

        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/apple.highschoolhelper.org-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/apple.highschoolhelper.org-access.log combined


    SSLEngine       on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/apple.highschoolhelper.org/apple.highschoolhelper.org_fullchain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile       /etc/letsencrypt/live/apple.highschoolhelper.org/apple.highschoolhelper.org_pkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Main domain certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Domain `apple.highschoolhelper.org` certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Unless you're using atypical filename suffixes, `.csr` refers to Certificate Signing Requests. The actual certificates would conventionally be `*.crt` or `*.cer`. On the other hand, `openssl x509` wouldn't accept a signing request as input in place of an actual certificate as far as I know. Are you sure you're fingerprinting the correct file? And does that file have just one certificate in it, not two? For example, the intermediate CA certificate + your actual certificate? The OpenSSL tools will typically use/check the first one found in the file and ignore any others.

Comment: @telcoM I have only `csr` file that is why I use `*`, my question is not updated to include the certificate in browser, and the one in server.

Comment: I already made multiple `httpd restart/ stop` but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate I can see in `https://highschoolhelper.org` right now is issued by "cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority". That suggests your hosting provider is using a cPanel system that overrides some parts of any configuration you do at the Apache configuration files, or possibly a set-up that manages the SSL/TLS support for all their customers in a centralized fashion.

You might have to use some sort of hosting control panel to configure the certificates for the main domain instead of modifying the webserver configuration directly.

There also might be some sort of automation in play at the hosting provider that runs at fixed intervals and updates some things, so some changes might not become visible on the internet as soon as you make them, but only after the automation has done its job.

If you are uncertain, please refer to your hosting provider's documentation or contact them for further instructions. Only they will know exactly how their system is set up.

The certificate I currently see at `https://apple.highschoolhelper.org` matches the certificate you posted for it, and the fingerprints also match.

According to your configuration, the certificate for `https://apple.highschoolhelper.org` should be found in file `/etc/letsencrypt/live/apple.highschoolhelper.org/apple.highschoolhelper.org_fullchain.crt` which does not match the `*.csr` you mentioned earlier - I guess you made some changes?

You can check the fingerprint of the certificate file at the server with:

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/apple.highschoolhelper.org/apple.highschoolhelper.org_fullchain.crt -noout -fingerprint -sha256
```

If that matches the SHA-256 fingerprint shown by your browser, that certificate is working correctly.

The main domain certificate you posted is a self-signed one, that has its Subject and Issuer fields both as `C=AU, ST=Aust, L=City, O=Default Company Ltd, CN=aws-host`. That looks like a default certificate generated by the hosting provider's automation, which may only be used between the virtual host and the provider's centralized system that provides the SSL/TLS for the main domain.

Comment: I am sure the vhost point to the right certificates, I make sure of that by changing the key size and check again in browser side to see if it is getting a new certificate.

Comment: I updated the question title, and add more details to my question.

Comment: I took the control off `highschoolhelper.org`, you were right cPanel causing the issue, I will wait for DNS propagation and update you back.

Comment: I started fresh, two new certificates are generated for each domain, but still I see both domains use one, and the fingerprint I generate is not the same one I saw in browser.